# How do I say "a loaf of bread"?

Tags: vocabulary

According to Google translate it is 一个面包, but that doesn't sound right.

How do I say "A loaf of bread"?

UPDATE:

This is what I mean by a "loaf" of bread. Not just a bun.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends a little bit on the type of bread.

For a long bread 条 is used. For a slice of bread 片 is used. 块 can also be used for a slice, but is also used for buns, a piece of bread or a complete bread.

Comment: 一个面包 is correct in "我要买一个面包" and "你赶紧把这个面包吃了". So I guess if you are not referring a specific piece, 个 works.

Comment: Yes you are right, 个 works. 个 normally always works, but often it's more authentic when more specific measure words are used.

Comment: @BertR Can you include examples? I'd be interested in seeing some actual sentence using it. Please, don't just link to Tatoeba.

Comment: @BertR By "authentic" do you mean "accurate"? It's probably native speakers that tend to overuse "个".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think native speakers can give you a definite answer simply because we don't eat bread that often here!

I would say something like 他吃了一整块切片面包 or 他吃了一整袋切片面包. 切片面包 is literally "sliced bread". Most of the bread you see in Chinese grocery stores (超市) is sliced.

Answer (score 1):

in verbal Chinese, you can just say 一个面包,

if you say 片, 块 etc. that seems a little formal.

In verbal Chinese, people don't care which measure word to use. We just say 个 in most situation.

note that just in verbal.

我吃了俩（or 两个）面包
她刚吃了1个番薯、1个面包、5块饼干、2个糖果…这样吃一餐,会不会长胖？

Comment: Hello Kevin and welcome to CL&U! :) Do you mind expanding a bit on your answer? If you include more detail you might receive more upvotes! :D

Comment: Thanks. :) Can we really use 个 mostly? It seems inappropriate to say "三个人" instead of "三口人".

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, we mostly use 个, not a accurate measure word. So 三个人 is exactly the verbal usage especially for young people. 隔壁宿舍住了8个人。

Comment: 口 is only for family member's count.

Comment: Only for family members? Not for people in general?

Comment: @Alenanno family members and villager(maybe since most Chinese village consist by one or few families). eg 广场上大约有三百人。 we won't say 三百口人. 王家庄有500口人（wang manor have 500 people）.

Comment: @Kevin - In your sentence 她刚吃了1个番薯、1个面包 it seems strange that a personal would eat a whole loaf. I don't feel 1个面包 clearly describes that someone ate a whole loaf of bread. If I heard this, I would think they just ate a bun or a smaller portion of bread. How would you clearly describe a loaf of bread (see image attached to my question).

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 if clearly describe, i suggest: 一大块面包。 In verbal we can say 她吃了半个 or 我们俩吃了一个 ，in verbal maybe 个 is 'overused' and 个 is not clear, but u can just 'overuse' it, no one will notice you 'overuse' 个.

Comment: Putting "片" in the answer is not helpful, as that means a _slice_ of bread.

Comment: @Alenanno 口 is used in population counts.

Answer (score 0):

一条面包is fine. same like 一条香烟 etc
http://www.15buy.cc/goods.php?id=6007

The link below is 一包香烟， it is soft page cover( if it's hard page cover , it's 一盒香烟，some of the time they are interchangable）
http://wenwen.soso.com/z/q139243191.htm?pid=ask.box